# New table create if not exists in database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in database naming "Customers". The table have total 83 columns. I want to create another "NewCustomers" table like "Customers" using php and mysql query. If the "NewCustomers" table exists in the database then it is no need to create the table if it is not then it will create the "NewCustomers" table.
I know there is a query

```
CREATE TABLE 'NewCustomers' LIKE 'Customers';
```

But it only creates the table like Customers if the New Customers not exists. How can I use

```
IF NOT EXISTS
```

in this regard?? I don't want to write all 83 columns name again like

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NewCustomers` (
        `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
        'name` varchar(250)  NOT NULL,    
        `data` varchar(100) NOT NULL default '',
        .
        .
        .
        PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
```

);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simple do like this

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NewCustomers` like `Customers`
```

**Note :**

And also it's safe to refer the `DB name` like below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `NewCustomers` like `DB_name`.`Customers`
```

Comment: Glad it help you :) @ALMAKSUD